# Liferay theme + maven

Tags: java, maven, liferay

I want create liferay theme, so I created a Maven project from archetype. My pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.liferay.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample-theme</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>sample-theme Theme</name>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.20</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>theme-merge</goal>
              <goal>build-css</goal>
              <goal>build-thumbnail</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
          <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
          <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
          <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
          <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
          <parentTheme>${liferay.theme.parent}</parentTheme>
          <pluginType>theme</pluginType>
          <themeType>${liferay.theme.type}</themeType>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
      <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
      <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
      <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
      <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <liferay.theme.parent>_styled</liferay.theme.parent>
    <liferay.theme.type>vm</liferay.theme.type>
  </properties>
</project>And I use maven:package and I see an error:
```

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sample-theme Theme 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.400s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 16 14:47:58 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'build-css' in plugin com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin:6.1.0 among available goals build-lang, build-wsdd, build-ext, build-service, direct-deploy, theme-merge, build-thumbnail, deploy -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
```

What is wrong? I am try change version liferay-maven-plugin but it not resolve my problem.

Comment: build-css is not one of the goals that are listed in the goals this plugin supports (from your maven error). Your output seems to think you are using plugin version 6.1.0 but your pom suggests 6.1.20 - what is the output for the pom you have listed?

Comment: So, how should I change my pom.xml?

Comment: I changed plugin version in pom to 6.1.0 and I have still an error

Comment: Can you edit your answer and give the output you receive for the pom you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Use version `6.1.1` as there is no `build-css` goal in `liferay-maven-plugin.jar` of `6.1.0` version

Take a look at `liferay-maven-plugin.jar/META-INF/maven/plugin.xml` for available goals.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a goal named as 'build-css'
Are you using groovy for your configuration file?
What you have pasted here is only a build file, for Maven's use.
Where are you other goals located, for example, look for "build-thumbnail" and "theme-merge"? Must be in a configuration file that this Maven build file is reading.
Where ever these other goals are, you need to create your goal there, or in a similar file. Then build again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entry build-css and build-thumbnail and deploy it again, or you can check the pom.xml file as an reference given in below link.

http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/5220131

Answer (score 0):

As others have written - 6.1.0 doesn't support 'build-css' goal, so you should delete or comment out following line in Your pom.xml:

```
<goal>build-css</goal>
```